# MongoDB Confusion with Schema Layout

Tags: mongodb

I am having trouble conceptualizing a MongoDB database. I watched a few crash courses and did some reading on the topic. But something I haven't found is how the schema is made or "conceptualized". My current understanding is that a mDB simply takes all documents you give it, and puts them into one giant "box" from which you make queries based on IDs or identifiers such as "SELECT * of "type": "foo".

Is this the right idea? Am I just submitting all documents into a giant box and letting the machine sift through it all?

Comment: well the syntax is more like : ```db.table.find({key:value})``` but MongoDB is a document storage. Relational databases generally store data in separate tables that are defined by the programmer, and a single object may be spread across several tables. Document databases store all information for a given object in a single instance in the database, and every stored object can be different from every other.

Comment: Thanks, I decided to instead just start playing with it and wrote a small answer below if what I was trying to find in case others stumble upon this question with a similar question

Answer (score 0):

So, answered my own question as I finally got the idea while playing around with it. For anyone else trying to get the idea for what it is "visually"

It is a giant box filled with "collections" that you call from.

You make this giant box with "use myNewDB"
That will make the database, but it is not stored until a document is put in.

For a single document, you can use "myNewDb.insert({FirstName : "Foo", LastName : "Bar"})"

However, if you want to keep specific documents together and separate from each other, you should make a collection.

To make a collection: "myNewDB.users.insert({userId : 1, FirstName : "Foo", LastName : "Bar"})"

the ".users" references a collection and will either use it or create it if it does not exist.

Adding "userId : 1" is a good practice as if you choose to remove this user, instead of removing all users named "Foo Bar", you can find the users named "Foo Bar" and properly remove the correct one based on their "userId".

To remove the proper "Foo Bar", first search all users with the name:
"SELECT * FROM myNewDB.users"

This will show all users, find the correct one to delete, in our case the only "Foo Bar" and remove by:
"myNewDB.users.remove({userID : 1})"

This will remove all documents with an instance of "userId : 1".

Caution though, improper data entry may lead to multiple users accidentally having the same userId, so be wary before deleting all entries with "userId: x"

Comment: userID is different from userId